# Grails unit test mock service return invalid object

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I am creating unit test for this (working fine) Grails service :

```
class CommonCodeService {

    def gridUtilService

    def getList(def params){
        def ret = null

        try {
            def res = gridUtilService.getDomainList(CommonCode, params)
            def rows = []
            def counter = 0
            res?.rows?.each{ // this is line 15
                rows << [
                        id: counter ++,
                        cell:[

                            it.key,  
                            it.value  
                        ]
                ]
            }

            ret = [rows: rows, totalRecords: res.totalRecords, page: params.page, totalPage: res.totalPage]

        } catch (e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw e
        }

        return ret
    }

}
```

This a method from collaborator `GridUtilService` :

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class GridUtilService {

    def getDomainList(Class domain, def params){
        /* some code */
        return [rows: rows, totalRecords: totalRecords, page: params.page, totalPage: totalPage]
    }
}
```

And this is my (not working) unit test for it :

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import com.emerio.baseapp.utils.GridUtilService

@TestFor(CommonCodeService)
@Mock([CommonCode,GridUtilService])
class CommonCodeServiceTests {

    void testGetList() {
        def rowList = [new CommonCode(key: 'value', value: 'value')]
        def serviceStub = mockFor(GridUtilService)
        serviceStub.demand.getDomainList {Map p -> [rows: rowList, totalRecords: rowList.size(), page:1, totalPage: 1]}
        service.gridUtilService = serviceStub.createMock()
        service.getList() // this is line 16
    }

}
```

When I run the test it shows exception :

```
No such property: rows for class: com.emerio.baseapp.CommonCodeServiceTests
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: rows for class: com.emerio.baseapp.CommonCodeServiceTests
    at com.emerio.baseapp.CommonCodeService.getList(CommonCodeService.groovy:15)
    at com.emerio.baseapp.CommonCodeServiceTests.testGetList(CommonCodeServiceTests.groovy:16)
```

It seems the mocked `GridUtilService` returns `CommonCodeServiceTests` instance instead of `Map`. What is wrong with my unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to fix your method params for the mocked `getDomainList()` call.  You have it as `Map m`, but it probably needs to be `Class c, Map m`.

From [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#mockingCollaborators),

> The closure arguments must match the number and types of the mocked method, but otherwise you are free to add whatever you want in the body.

Why a miss on the arguments behaves the way it does is a stumper.  I can replicate your problem using my own stripped-down classes.  I also found that the returned type for a call on the method when there's a param miss is a closure of the test class, which, for my simple case at least, can then be `.call()`'ed to get the desired (mocked) result.  I'm not sure if this behavior supports some kind of functionality or is a bug.  It's certainly confusing.

Comment: yes it works! I need to define a same arguments for the closure as in the mocked method. Thanks